# How to automate saving file from Internet Explorer 11 in VBA on 64-bit machine

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

Have an Excel file at this location: https://ufr.osd.state.ma.us/DM/GetDoc.aspx?DocId=165350&Library=EFILEDMProd

You can see there's a hyperlink titled "Download" at the top. Need to automate the saving of this file using VBA in Excel through Internet Explorer 11 on a 64-bit machine. Ideally, I'd also like to save the file in a specific path and with a specific file name ("2018-042389332.xls", in this case). Trouble is that I cannot find a way to direct download the file, so I'm left to deal with the File Save dialog box that is tricky to interact with. So far I've tried using SendKeys with inconsistent results.

Here's the relevant part of the code I'm using. So far it works to click on the "Download" button, pulls up the File Save dialog at the bottom, and in some instances, follows through with saving the file as the default file name.

```
    IE.Document.getElementById("LinkButton2").Click
    SendKeys "{F6}", True
    SendKeys "{TAB}", True
    SendKeys "{DOWN}", True
    SendKeys "{DOWN}", True
    SendKeys "{ENTER}", True

    SendKeys "{TAB}", True
    SendKeys "{TAB}", True
    SendKeys "{TAB}", True
    SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
```

Comment: Can you use open source software? i.e. selenium basic vba

Comment: So the code is part of a larger code that loops through a list in a spreadsheet and gets the corresponding file for 180 other companies. I haven't found an open source program that could work for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of interacting with the file dialog, make IE download the file directly. Then use a function that returns the name of the latest file in a folder (IE's download folder) so you know which one is the file you just downloaded.

```
Function LatestFile(StrDefaultFolder As String) As String

Dim LatestDate As Date

StrCurrentFile = Dir(StrDefaultFolder)

Do While Len(StrCurrentFile) > 0

    StrFullFileName = StrDefaultFolder & StrCurrentFile

    If FileDateTime(StrFullFileName) > LatestDate Then
        LatestDate = FileDateTime(StrFullFileName)
        LatestFile = StrCurrentFile
    End If

    StrCurrentFile = Dir
Loop

End Function
```

Now, you can copy-paste and rename the file as you like:

```
Sub MoveAndRenameFile()

StrLastFile = LatestFile("C:\Users\YourUserName\Downloads\")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.CopyFile StrLastFile, "C:\SomeFolder\NewFilename.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll make this work for the save portion but I'm still struggling with how to direct download.

Comment: How do you make IE download direct without interacting with file dialog?

Comment: There used to be an option _Always ask before opening this filetype_ that you could uncheck. Based on other threads this option is no longer available unfortunately. My idea won't work then.

Answer (score 1):

To get more consistent results I would try to wait a second after each send keys, try inserting this after each sendkey:

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
```

Do you need to be using internet explorer? If you have the direct download link this would be way easier

```
Dim HttpReq As Object, myURL As String
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    myURL = *direct download link*
    HttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "", ""
    HttpReq.send
    myURL = HttpReq.responseBody
    If HttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStrm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStrm.Open
        oStrm.Type = 1
        oStrm.Write HttpReq.responseBody
        oStrm.SaveToFile *File Path with file name and extension*,1 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStrm.Close
    End If
```

Comment: I would love to direct download but am not sure if it's possible here. All I can find from the site's HTML for the download link is: `<a id="LinkButton2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('LinkButton2','')">Download</a>"`, but not sure if or how to make that into a direct download.

Comment: Also, thanks for the suggestion on the wait. I had tried that too but I was still finding it inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **URLDownloadToFile** function for direct downloading the file using VBA code.

Here is the sample code that you directly try to run from your Excel VBA module.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub download_HK_picture()
imgsrc = "https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/298/docs/ir211wk12sample.xls"
dlpath = "C:\"
URLDownloadToFile 0, imgsrc, dlpath & "ir211wk12sample.xls", 0, 0
End Sub
```

Further, you can modify the code as per your own requirement.

Reference:

(1) [Download Files with VBA URLDownloadToFile](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/download-files-with-vba-urldownloadtofile/)

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't have or at least cannot find a direct download link. If you inspect the HTML for the download link, it's running some JavaScript function to get the file download.

Comment: If you are in a contact of the developers of that site than you can request for a link may save your lot of work. If they are not available to provide any information than you need to continue with your inconsistent current approach.